# Union one field but sum others from separate tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with the following columns:

```
SalesTable - invnum, brand, turnover, gp with values:

 1. Pepsi, 30000, 15000
 2. Coke, 40000, 20000
 3. Mountain Dew, 10000, 3000
 4. Dr Pepper, 5000, 2300
 5. Pepsi, 10000, 5000


SalesOrderTable - ordernum, brand, ordervalue, ordergp
with values:

 1. Pepsi, 50000, 25000
 2. Coke, 20000, 15000
 3. Vitamin Water, 30000, 12000
 4. Coke, 10000, 5000
```

I need to union the brand column from both tables so the unique values from both tables are shown with the sum of all the other columns. The result should look like this:

```
brand, inv_value, inv_gp, order_value, order_gp

Pepsi         40000 20000 50000 25000

Coke          40000 20000 30000 20000

Mountain Dew  10000  3000     0     0

Dr Pepper      5000  2300     0     0

Vitamin Water     0     0 30000 12000
```

Thank you!

Comment: Cross verify your result data.Because Result data and table data not clear

Comment: Hi Mansoor. I checked again and the result data correlates with what I need. I need the SalesTables values summed and the OrderTable values summed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
SELECT * FROM SalesTable 
NATURAL JOIN SalesOrderTable

Answer (score 0):

I think this is also fine with the requirement: simple and easy achieved by union all and aggregation function:

```
select brand, 
    sum(t.turnover) turnover, 
    sum(t.gp) gp, 
    sum(t.ordervalue) ordervalue, 
    sum(t.ordergp) ordergp from 
    (
    select brand, turnover, gp, 0 ordervalue, 0 ordergp 
    from #SalesTable 
    union all
    select brand, 0, 0, ordervalue,ordergp 
    from #SalesOrderTable ) t group by t.brand
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this.

```
            create table #SalesTable
            (
            invnum int,
            brand varchar(20),
            turnover int,
            gp int
            )


            insert into #SalesTable values
            (1, 'Pepsi', 30000, 15000),
            (2,'Coke', 40000, 20000),
            (3,'Mountain Dew',10000,3000),
            (4,'Dr Pepper', 5000, 2300),
            (5,'Pepsi', 10000, 5000)


            create table #SalesOrderTable
            (
            ordernum int,
            brand varchar(20),
            ordervalue int,
            ordergp int
            )


            insert into #SalesOrderTable values
            (1,'Pepsi', 50000, 25000),
            (2,'Coke', 20000, 15000),
            (3,'Vitamin Water', 30000, 12000),
            (4,'Coke', 10000, 5000)


            select distinct 
            coalesce( st.brand,so.brand) as Brand,
            coalesce( st.turnover,'0') as inv_value,
            coalesce( st.gp,'0') as inv_gp,
            coalesce( so.ordervalue,'0') as order_value,
            coalesce( SO.ordergp,'0') as order_gp
            from
            (
            select brand,sum(ordervalue) as ordervalue ,sum(ordergp) as ordergp from  #SalesOrderTable
            group by brand
            )so 
             full outer join  
            (
            select brand,SUM(turnover) as turnover,SUM(gp) as gp from  #SalesTable
            group by brand
            )ST
            on SO.brand=ST.brandon SO.brand=ST.brand
```

Comment: @user3409529  have you checked this ?

Comment: @user3409529  mw . mark It as answer . and vote up . if its working